# Poner mayuscula la primera letra de cada palabra en C

Tags: c

Tengo que conseguir con una función poner las primeras letras de cada palabra en mayúsculas, las palabras están contenidas en un array.

Esta es la **función** sobre la que trabajo:

```
void cambiar_a_mayusculas(char palabras[250]){
  int cambio=0;
  char* ptr = palabras;
  while( *ptr != '\0' ){
    //isalpha comprueba si es una letra
    while( !isalpha(*ptr)  ){
      ptr++;
      cambio=0;
    }
    if( isalpha(*ptr) ){
      if( *ptr >= 'a' && cambio==0){
        //toupper cambia la letra a mayuscula
        *ptr = toupper(*ptr);
        cambio=1;
      }
      ptr++;
    }
  }
}
```

En el **main** tengo:

```
int main()
{
    char palabras [250];
    printf("Introduzca un texto de maximo 250 caracteres: \n");
    fgets(palabras, 250, stdin);
    printf("\n%s",palabras);
    cambiar_a_mayusculas(palabras);
    printf("\n------------------\n%s", palabras);
    return 0;
}
```

El problema llega en la salida, muestro un ejemplo:

**Entrada:**

> Abcd efghI jklMN oPq

**Salida:**

> ABcd EfghI JKlMN OPq

**Salida buscada:**

> Abcd EfghI JklMN OPq

Como se puede ver con este ejemplo la función sí cambia la primera letra a mayúscula pero en algunos casos (que no he conseguido identificar ni cuando ni por que) también pasa la segunda letra a mayúscula.

En este ejemplo también es importante destacar que solo me interesa cambiar la primera letra, el resto de la palabra me da igual.

***MUCHAS GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > Poner mayuscula la primera letra de cada palabra en C

Un algoritmo muy sencillo, es tener una variable (que guarde solo 1 y 0) que nos indique si la letra es la primera de X palabra. Por lo tanto, le podemos dar un significado a los valores que reciba esta variable:

- Si la variable recibe el valor de `1`, quiere decir que estamos en la primera letra.
- Si la variable recibe el valor de `0`, quiere decir que NO estamos en la primera letra.

Obviamente, este algoritmo solo funcionará si cada palabra está separado por un espacio:

```c
void cambiar_a_mayusculas(char* palabras)
{
    for(int primeraLetra = 1; *palabras; ++palabras)
    {
        if(primeraLetra && isalpha(*palabras))
        {
            *palabras = toupper(*palabras);
            primeraLetra = 0;
        }
        if(*palabras == ' ')
            primeraLetra = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias, además de ayudarme a encontrar el error lo he comprendido.